# Explain a snippet of c++ codes

Tags: c++, quantile

I just started learning "class" and other advanced techniques in C++ in order to understand the following C++ snippet. Please don't down rate the question if you think it's silly because I've searched online before asking!

The code implements an online quantile algorithm called 'GK method'. I try to understand the practical work flow of the algorithm by learning the code. The full code has 191 lines so I didn't copy it here, it is located at:
https://github.com/coolwanglu/quantile-alg/blob/master/gk.h

The part of the code I don't understand is list below:

```
46     class entry{ 
47     public: 
48         entry () { } 
49         entry (unsigned int _g, unsigned int _d) : g(_g), delta(_d) { } 
50         unsigned int g,delta; 
51     };
```

I don't understand what #48,49 means.

```
134         entry & ecur = iter->second;
```

Here what does "Type & Name" mean?

Finally, if anyone who's familar with GK method happen to see this: Could you explain to me, or suggest any references that explain the practical implementation of this method. Thanks.

Comment: The first two are constructors, and the second is a reference.  Any good C++ book can explain those.

Comment: `class` is not an advanced feature of C++, it is the most basic foundation of the language (separate from inherited features of C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Line 48 is a *default constructor*. This is the code that gets invoked when you declare a variable of type `entry`, and do not specify initialization parameters.
- Line 49 is another constructor. This is the code that gets invoked when you declare a variable of type `entry`, and pass two `unsigned int` parameters.
- Line 134 is a declaration of a *reference* of type `entry`. The ampersand says that `ecur` is not a copy of `iter->second`, but rather a reference to it. Any change to `ecur` would be reflected in `iter->second`, because they refer to the same variable.

You can read more about constructors [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm).
Here is [a tutorial on reference variables](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html).